# Redirect to different page on Browser Refresh Button Click

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I want the user to be redirected to a different page on click of the browser refresh button but I am unable to do so. I have tried using onbeforeunload but it does not seem to work for my requirement as it gives a message of Leave and Stay but even that does not seem to be working on chrome. So how can I redirect the user to a different page on click of browser refresh button.

The Code that I tried:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Rushabh

Comment: What have you tried so far? And please provide some codes for clarity.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question and added a sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check `performance.getEntriesByType` on page load . here is how you can try so .

```js
function checkEvt(){
    var evTypep=window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type;
       if (evTypep=='reload'){
         window.location.replace("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
       }
      
}
checkEvt();
```

Comment: if statement can be rewritten as `evTypep != "navigate"` to accomodate page refresh through back and previous buttons of browser

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    location.href='https://www.google.com';
  } else {
    console.log( "Not reloaded");
  }
```